# CodeIgniter - fetch and display data from n-2-n relation tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, fetch

Hi I'd like some help please. I have created 3 database tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`description` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
`feature_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`features_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`feature_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_features` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`feature_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`feature_value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The relations between them is many-to-many as one product can have many features and a feature can belong to more than one product, but each product has a specific value for each feature.

**My goal is to fetch all features and their values that belong to a specific product** and then display them in a form (in my view) where I can assign new values or edit existing ones for the features of the product. To give you a sort example of how my view looks like:

```
// Assign new values or edit existing ones
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
    <table class="table">
        <?php echo form_hidden('product_id', $product->product_id); ?>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Feature</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if(count($features) > 0): foreach($features as $feature): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo form_hidden('feature_id[]', $feature->feature_id); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $feature->feature_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('value[]',set_value('value[]', $feature->value)); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; else: ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h4 align="center">No Features available</h4></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <?php echo form_submit('save_feature', 'Save Features', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I'm trying to build the query in phpmyadmin (in order to create it with Active Record) and testing the results. Here's the query

```
SELECT `features`.`feature_id` , `features`.`feature_name` , `product_features`.`value`
FROM `features`
LEFT JOIN `product_features` ON `features`.`feature_id` = `product_features`.`feature_id`
/* WHERE `product_features`.`product_id` =1 */
```

Without the WHERE statement I get as result like so:

```
feature_id |feature_name | value
1          | Processor   | NULL
2          | RAM         | NULL
3          | Hard Disk   | NULL
```

but if I include and the WHERE statement (remember that I want the values of the specific product) I get no results. How can I fix this, or what changes should I make to correct things??? Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE 1: A little detail: The product_features table is currently empty as there have been no assignments yet (I start from scratch), so I guess I may have to create my query dynamicly.

NOTE 2: I have assigned to features the (parent)category_id eg Computers, Digital Cameras etc etc, so I guess I have also to specify and the category_id to the query in order to get the corect features. (e.g. Apple Imac (in Computers category) should not have the feature optical zoom included as it belongs in Digital Cameras category).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN `product_features` ON `features`.`feature_id` = `product_features`.`feature_id`
and `product_features`.`product_id` =1

replace where to and as above

Comment: I've tested it in phpmyadmin and works ok! my question is how this is going to be converted in active record now? the user guide of CI doesn't have any AND() or similar function

Comment: please try `->join('product_features', 'features.feature_id = product_features.feature_id and product_features.product_id =1', 'left')`

Comment: I'm not quite sure if its correct as in product_features.product_id = 1,  1 is the product_id and this value will be passed as a parameter in a method (something like this product_features.product_id = $product_id). Haven't test it though..

Comment: @Lykos ofc as `$variable` not as pure `1`, I thought it is unnecessary to write that down :D.

Comment: Yes I just thought to mention it. Anyway it works, although it returns all features even those which belong to other categories. I need to also specify and from which category they belong to, eg whether they are in Computers, Digital Cameras etc etc (see Note 2)

Comment: Ok! Found it! I just did a where('category_id', $category_id) statement after the join(), and fetched all correct data! I guess I have to find out now if it will return the values when I asing them.